# Chronicle Bytes from InputStream

Tags: java, performance, chronicle, low-level-io, chronicle-bytes

I'm trying to use saxophone for parsing json to protobuf message on the fly, and want to avoid creating string instances for each response.

For that i need to create Bytes instance from InputStream (that is provided from apache http entity).

I'm digging sources for a while but cant find way to do that... any suggestions?

Comment: Hi vach, please share some of your code, without code, people are likely to skip your question.

Comment: will do next time, for now i have the solution besides question is quite self explanatory, take any inputstream and turn it into Bytes to use in openhft projects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two ways you can do this.

```
// reuse a string builder if the String cannot be pooled easily
stringBuilder.setLength(0);
bytes.parseUTF(stringBuilder, StopCharTesters.ALL);
```

or you can use the built in String pool

```
String s = bytes.parseUTF(StopCharTesters.ALL);
```

This will work well if there is a relative small number of possible Strings (at least most of the time)

Comment: Thanks Peter, is there some kind of a guide to general purpose projects like wire or bytes? I've just getting started with these awesome libs but i'm figuring out things looking at tests and generally reading source...

Comment: Wire has basic docs https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire but Bytes needs much more https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes  I am more than happy to answer questions and accept pull requests for improved docs.